# Does outputstream.write(int c) in java overwrite the previous stream dat with byte c or does it increment it?

Tags: java, stream, iostream, outputstream

Will writing to an output stream from an input stream one byte at a time increment the stream content by the written byte or will it replace the current stream with this byte? If I want the stream to contain several bytes at once do I have to write a byte array to it, or use an appropriate java class function for the specified data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output streams are sequences of data. If you write new data to a stream, that data will follow any previous data, neither incrementing it nor replacing it. Imagine that the stream is being sent along a wire directly. Sending a new piece of information doesn't affect what went before.

Comment: There is no `OutputStream.write(byte)`, only `OutputStream.write(int)`, like the OP posted. (And as the Javadoc states: "The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument <code>b</code>. The 24 high-order bits of <code>b</code> are ignored.")

Comment: So they're sort of like queues? One piece of data follows the other? Do we have to access the data in the front to "pop" it, e.g. in java inputstream read(), and be able to read the next piece of data?

Comment: `OutputStream` is an abstract class, so it only defines how one should be able to use the stream, not what it then does with the information. Depending on what kind of `OutputStream` you have, it could be writing to a network socket, writing to a file, or writing to a byte array. You could use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write data to a byte array sequentially, and then extract the byte array and use it for a `ByteArrayInputStream`, which would allow you to read the same data back sequentially.